# How to pass 2D puzzle from file

Tags: c++, file

i have a puzzle in a file and i am trying to pass this puzzle to 2D array but i cant determine the new line so i could not pass to new row. This is puzzle :

```
                00 00 00 00 01 02 04 05 00
                00 00 00 06 08 09 10 12 13
                00 00 00 17 19 14 15 18 07
                00 00 00 20 21 23 25 24 29
                22 26 28 35 34 31 33 38 39
                bb 30 31 34 32 36 03 11 16
```

i am reading like this:

```
string FileName;
fstream puzzle;
cout << "Please Enter the File Name : "  ;
cin >> FileName;
puzzle.open(FileName);
string s;
while(puzzle >> s){

    if(s == "bb"){
        arr[i][j] = 100;
        j++;
        counter++;
    }
    else{
        arr[i][j] = stoi(s);
        j++;
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) you may think a design where you will say number of rows and columns ahead of the reading the puzzle e.g. in this file as first 2 numbers
2) you may read by lines via getline() and parse string later

Comment: This is a good *use case* for `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` will dynamically expand during runtime, when you don't know the size of the data at compile time.  Arrays need their sizes known at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the file line by line. In this case you only have to add one loop

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Please Enter the File Name : ";
    std::cin >> filename;
    std::ifstream puzzle(filename);
    if(!puzzle.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Can't open file" << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(puzzle, line)) {
        arr.emplace_back();
        std::stringstream str(line);
        std::string s;
        while(str >> s) {
            if(s == "bb") {
                arr.back().emplace_back(100);
            } else {
                arr.back().emplace_back(std::stoi(s));
            }
        }
    }

    for (const auto &line : arr) {
        for (const auto &field : line) {
            std::cout << field << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```